# TypeError: obj.checkValidity is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have developed a form, in the validation of the fields it shows an error of "obj.checkValidity is not a function", when there is empty field it works correctly but when all the fields are with data it shows this error

I'm working with asp.net together with jquery

```
var _checkDivValidity = function (elem) {

        var passValidation = true;

        $(elem).find("[required]").each(function (i, obj) {

            if (!obj.checkValidity()) {

                obj.reportValidity();

                passValidation = false;

                return;
            }
        });
        return passValidation;
    };
```

I hope the result is true and send the information of the corresponding forms.

[image: Screenshot of error and stacktrace in Chrome DevTools console]
[image: Source of error]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.NET so I have removed that tag.  The fact that you use VB.NET in your application does not mean that it is relevant to a question about JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows us to see the error

Comment: Note that the error shown conflicts with the code shown ... there is no `obj[0]` in the question code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a search on this command, because I did not know it, so I understood it works only with selects, I would confirm if this is the case, because if it does not make sense to give the error, my suggestion is as follows

```
var _checkDivValidity = function (elem) {

    var passValidation = true;

    $(elem).find("select[required]").each(function (i, obj) {

        if (!obj.checkValidity()) {

            obj.reportValidity();

            passValidation = false;

            return;
        }
    });
    return passValidation;
};
```